# How to create html markup for gmail highlight cards (confirmation cards)?

Tags: gmail

What is the correct working markup schema for the highlight card for the mail template in Gmail?

We have tried the script of ld+json as given in the google docs for rendering the highlight key cards in the Gmail for our html template

But the highlight card is not rendering in Gmail